# CAML query not working when week has split month i.e 31st-4th only return 31st

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, caml

So, I have been using this query in my SharePoint app for Months and its has always worked perfectly fine. But i just realized that if the week I'm trying to get has a split month like July 31st to August 4th, it will only return List Items for July 31st??? I've tried everything I can think of to get this to work and nothing. How do I get it to work? I'm at a loss. Tried using daterange overlap tag, it just fails the query, tried every other format of date I could think of, just returns an empty enumerator. Looked through MSDN for hours, No help on this issue, searched google and stack overflow for a few hours and can not find an answer to this question. It works just fine in all my querys except

```js
 startDate = startDate.toISOString();
    endDate = endDate.toISOString();
    
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var filterString = '<View><Query>';
    filterString = filterString + '<Where>';
    filterString = filterString + '<And>';
    filterString = filterString + '<Geq>';
    filterString = filterString + '<FieldRef Name=\'EstimatedDelivery\'/>';
    filterString = filterString + '<Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type = \'DateTime\'>' + startDate + '</Value>';
    filterString = filterString + '</Geq>';
    filterString = filterString + '<Leq>';
    filterString = filterString + '<FieldRef Name=\'EstimatedDelivery\'/>';
    filterString = filterString + '<Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type = \'DateTime\'>' + endDate + '</Value>';
    filterString = filterString + '</Leq>';
    filterString = filterString + '</And>';
    filterString = filterString +'</Where>';
    filterString = filterString + '</Query></View>';
```

```html
 <View>
      <Query>
        <Where>
          <And>
            <Geq>
              <FieldRef Name='EstimatedDelivery'/>
              <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>startDate</Value>
            </Geq>
            <Leq>
              <FieldRef Name='EstimatedDelivery'/>
              <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>endDate</Value>
            </Leq>
          </And>
        </Where>
      </Query>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems no one can figure out why CAML fails on weeks that are split into two months, so changed out the CAML queries for rest calls and now everything works and is about 12 times faster!

```
var url = "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/Items?" +
        "$orderby=EstimatedDelivery&$filter=EstimatedDelivery ge datetime'"
+ startDate + "' and EstimatedDelivery le datetime'" + endDate + "'";

getItems(url, retrieveCalendarListItemsSucceeded);

function getItems(url,  callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            callback(data.d.results);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```